# Mpdf 7.1 creates pdf file, writes all the text but no HTML tags or CSS

Tags: php, mpdf

First of all, I use a public shared server, and I unable to use composer, and I use my own autoload.

The simptoms are clear:

- php version 7.2
- Mpdf version 7.1
- every needed component are loaded for Mpdf, and nothing wrong on the log, but debug informations like this:

  [2018-05-29 15:44:07] [ debug ] PDF generated in 0.193712 seconds
  [2018-05-29 15:44:08] [ debug ] Compiled in 0.634812 seconds
  [2018-05-29 15:44:08] [ debug ] Peak Memory usage 4.00 MB
  [2018-05-29 15:44:08] [ debug ] PDF file size 16 kB
  [2018-05-29 15:44:08] [ debug ] 1 fonts used

I can open the created file, but it contains only the text part of the content, without a single table or style.

Any suggestion?

**Edit 1**

I've tried these html structures:

```
$pdfContent = '<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <base href="'._PAGE_BASE_URL.'/">
        <style>
            '.file_get_contents('libs/css/reset.css').'
            '.file_get_contents('libs/css/pdf.css').'
        </style>
        </head><body>';
```

and

```
$pdfContent = '<html><head></head><body>';
```

Of course I used some table, div and span elements with the following PDF render commands:

```
$mpdf=new \Mpdf\Mpdf();
$mpdf->WriteHTML($pdfContent, 0);
$mpdf->Output('test.pdf');
```

I've tried to use only the body content for the HTML source and tried to use it with this:

```
$mpdf=new \Mpdf\Mpdf();
$mpdf->WriteHTML(file_get_contents('libs/css/reset.css').PHP_EOL.file_get_contents('libs/css/pdf.css'),1);
$mpdf->WriteHTML($pdfContent, 2);
$mpdf->Output('test.pdf');
```

Comment: *Any suggestion?* Yes, post some code, so we can help you.

Comment: Sure thing, I've updated the post.

Comment: Public shared server is not an excuse to not use composer - you can still have composer prepare the autoloading in your local development environment and just upload the result.

Answer (score 0):

So I made some tests, and it turns out, that the code recognize, and successfully use the CSS files already, and the only missing part is, to use the HTML tags.

That was the point where I started to suspect myself. Did I really load all the necessary files for the Mpdf? It turns out, I didn't. After I realised I wasn't understanding it, I made a simple load-in-all-file "autoloader", and included on the very beginning in the src/Mpdf.php file.

I've run 2 tests, and 'et voila. Everything is in it's place. Unfortunately, I still don't know what were the missing part(s) from it, but after one and a half week tryouts, I'm not really care about it.

If somebody wants to use Mpdf's newer versions, but can't use Composer, I suggest to forget about it. But if it not bothers you to use some really messed up, and stupid code to make it works (like me in this case), feel free to use the loader below to load all the necessary (and bunch of not really needed) files from the Mpdf projects directory:

```
function loadDirContent($dir){
    $dirContent = scandir($dir);
    foreach($dirContent as $item){
        $path = $dir."/".$item;

        // avoid unnecessary examination and load
        if($item == '.' || $item == '..' || 
           $item == 'Loader.php' || $item == 'Mpdf.php' || 
           strpos($path, "Psr/Log/Test")!==false || 
           (!is_dir($path) && strtolower(substr($item, -3)) != 'php')){
               continue;
        }

        if(!is_dir($path)){
            require_once($path);
        } else {
            // The Tag folder contains some dependency on folder contents
            // These files have to load first
            if(strpos($path, "src/Tag") !== false){
                require_once($path."/Tag.php");
                require_once($path."/InlineTag.php");
                require_once($path."/BlockTag.php");
                require_once($path."/NewColumn.php");
            }

            loadDirContent($path);
        }
    }
}

loadDirContent(__DIR__);
```

In the Mpdf/src/Mpdf.php file you have to require the loader file, what I stored in the same directory as the Mpdf.php

```
require_once(__DIR__."/Loader.php");
```

and of course the Psr/Log package is needed too, that I downloaded manually from it's GitHub repository, and extracted it to the Mpdf/src directory. The Mpdf need it and use it, so in the Mpdf/src/Mpdf.php you have to call this two line too:

```
require_once(__DIR__."/Psr/Log/LoggerAwareInterface.php");
require_once(__DIR__."/Psr/Log/NullLogger.php");
```

in these files need some "in-project-requires" and if you dont use autoloder, you have to add some extra require_once lines in them.

I know it's stupid, and ugly, but finally it works, like it worked with the 5th version of the Mpdf, and now, I am just happy about it.